# windows 8 start command

Tags: windows-8, command-line

I'm with a company that makes communication devices for people with speech impairments. To make a long story short, we have a tool that opens files. It's equivalent to the run dialogue box. Most of the time we can just put the full path to an .exe file and the program starts with no problem but we just ran into one that doesn't work. I've come to the conclusion that the problem is I need to somehow pass the "Start in" path along with the executable. I think you can do this with the built-in start command I found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true) 


But I can't figure out how to write the command! I've tried the following but get an error:

```
start \d"C:\Program Files\Bookshare\ReadOutLoud Bookshare\Applications\" "C:\Program Files\Bookshare\ReadOutLoud Bookshare\Applications\ReadOutLoud_Bookshare.exe"
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Assuming you copy/pasted that, your switch is off. `start \d` should be `start /d`. If that doesn't fix it, you should edit your question and add the error text.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to start should be a null-string for your example.  This has basically been asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154075/using-the-dos-start-command-with-parameters-passed-to-the-started-program

Comment: Well, your answers gave me a clue. I'm just getting a message saying Windows cannot find start. So now I'm wondering if Windows 8 has some command? I have tried searching on-line but with such a generic term, I can't find anything

Comment: Per another comment, change your option to "/d", and add a space after it, plus the empty string I mentioned. If that doesn't work, repost your exact (new) command and the exact error.

Comment: I figured out I could use cmd with the /C switch. Thanks for the help